# Oracle select query that create dummy column with hardcoded value

Tags: oracle, row-number

I have this records, and i want to create an oracle select query to produce dummy column with 1,2,3 as value.  Please help thanks.

```
field1

one
two
three
four
five 
six
seven
eight
```

basically i want to add dummy column with value from 1 to 3 only.  once it reaches 3 it goes back to 1 again.

```
field1   dummycol
one       1
two       2
three     3
four      1
five      2
six       3
seven     1
eight     2
```

Comment: Do you want every ordered third written number to be the same number? For example, do you need one, four, and seven to all be 1?

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism you use here is to include the fixed value as a named column, like

```
select '1' as one
```

For your case use something like

```
select '1' as one, '2' as two, '3' as three, '1' as four, '2' as five, '3' as six, '1' as seven, '3' as eight
```

This mechanism often comes into play when you are making a union of several queries and want the result to indicate something about each source, like

```
select name, date, 'student' as Type from student
union
select name, date, 'teacher' as Type from teacher
union
select name, date, 'alumni' as Type from alumni
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use the `rownum` pseudo column and the `mod` function:

```
select field1, mod(rownum - 1, 3) + 1
from <your table>;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dadba/1)

But that doesn't work quite as expected if the query [has an order-by clause](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dadba/2), even [in a subquery](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dadba/3), and presumably you want do want some order to be imposed and the cycling number to be allied against that final order.

You can use the analytic `row_number()` function to do that instead:

```
select field1,
  mod(row_number() over (order by null) - 1, 3) + 1 as dummycol
from <your table>
order by field1;

FIELD1     DUMMYCOL
---------- --------
eight             1
five              2
four              3
one               1
seven             2
six               3
three             1
two               2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dadba/6)